# Making an async API call on ComponentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a ReactJS that is expecting a list of artist objects. I read the ReactJS docs, and found this:

[image: reactjs docs]

So I thought, Ok, I'll fire off my `fetchArtists()` action (I'm using Redux) from within the `componentDidMoun()` method.

I am doing that, but for some reason it isn't working. The list of artists I'm getting back is `undefined` even thought in the logger, I can see that the artists were returned.

**CODE**

Here's the app container component.

```
class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(ArtistsListActions.fetchArtists());
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Header />
        <Route exact path="/" render={routeProps => <ArtistList {...routeProps} artists={this.props.artists} />} />
        <Route exact path="/artist/:artistUrlName" component={Artist} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ArtistList.propTypes = {
  artists: PropTypes.array.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = function(state) {
  console.log('The state is:');
  console.log(state);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

The `console.log(state);` within the `mapStateToProps()` method should show me a state with artists loaded, but I don't, `artists` is an empty array at that point.

[image: console screenshot]

**UPDATE**

I did what you all suggested about returning an option in my `mapStateToProps()` method, but that still doesn't work. I've captured what is happening in [this screencast](https://www.screencast.com/t/5DjUjGblm).

Comment: Your mapStateToProps function needs to return an object with the props of the React component as properties. You are not returning anything, hence the “undefined” error message.

Comment: @PatrickHund, but when I `console.log(state)`, shouldn't I at least see the artists there?

Comment: No, not the first time the component is rendered. If you use _componentDidMount_ to dispatch an action, that means (1) the component is rendered and attached to the DOM (2) the redux action is dispatched (3) the data is fetched (4) the state is updated with the fetched data (5) the component is rendered again, with the data from the state

Comment: I think you forgot dispatchToProps method...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This fails due to Redux do not get expected result from mapStateToProps method, which should return Object to be merged to Component props. It is treat as developer's failure therefore Redux breaks the loop and do not process events anymore, forcing dev to fix it.

Also there is shortcut for `this.props.dispatch(ArtistsListActions.fetchArtists())`, if you pass function as a second parameter to connect it will automatically wrap it within dispatch and make wrapped function available under props:

```
class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchArtists();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Header />
        <Route exact path="/" render={routeProps => <ArtistList {...routeProps} artists={this.props.artists} />} />
        <Route exact path="/artist/:artistUrlName" component={Artist} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ArtistList.propTypes = {
  artists: PropTypes.array.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = function(state) {
  console.log('The state is:');
  console.log(state);
  const artists = state.artists.artists && state.artists.artists.verified;
  return {artists: artists || []};
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  fetchArtists: ArtistsListActions.fetchArtists;
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Comment: Thanks @MaxVorobjev, see updated question for what is happening

Comment: This happens because render method expecting artists to be Array, while state.artists.artists.verified sometimes undefined. This can be fixed as per above, see modified `mapStateToProps` in the answer

Comment: Can you please tell me what is happening here? `state.artists.artists && state.artists.artists.verified;`

Comment: it's null-coalescing for the artists property on state.artists. if it is there, it get's the verified array, otherwise returns false as state.artists.artists is null.
the return line then either returns the verified array or and empty array - either of which will allow your code to run.

Answer (score 1):

The error is being thrown before your axios call. The initial state does not match the shape of the response from your api.

You can either try and normalise this through your actionCreators or update your inital state to match the API:

```
const initialState = {
  isFetching: false,
  fetchComplete: false,
  artists: {artists: {verified:[]}},
  error: null
};
```

For completeness, this is the mapStateToProps you would need if you change your initial state:

```
const mapStateToProps = function(state) {
    console.log(state);
  return {
        artists: state.artists.artists.verified
    }
}
```

Comment: what is an easy way of inspecting my `state` object? maybe the artist array sits under `state.artists.artists.verified`, but I'm not sure yet, how can I inspect? After doing what you suggested, I'm [getting this error](https://www.screencast.com/t/sJX7vU7CAF).

Comment: can we see your actionCreator for ArtistsListActions - also you don't appear to have mapped dispatch to props

Comment: Sure [here it is](https://gist.github.com/Ciwan1859/c4020b33f353cd3cdfd461240b46e4c5). Isn't the `mapDispatchToProps()` just a short-hand as Max mentioned?

Comment: Here's [the reducer](https://gist.github.com/Ciwan1859/dc1f36f9b0ae5ec4dd9fc1da28cba54b) for the artists list.

Comment: from everything you've linked, i think you're right in that your array sits in state.artists.artists.verified. This is because you've created a property in your state with the key artists, then assigned an object to it which has a key 'artists' - hence the double artists. changing the code in my answer above to return {artists: state.artists.artists.verified should sort it. The easiest way to see you state at any time is just just console.log it before your return statements in your reducer and actionCreators

Comment: I tried that, not sure if you watched [the screencast](https://www.screencast.com/t/5DjUjGblm), but that didn't work either :(

Comment: Thanks @hairmot, I did this `artists: { verified: [], uverified: [] }` but I still had to do what Max said to get it to work :) Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So, you probably forgot dispatch to props...

```
class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetch(); //Call just your mapped dispatch
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Header />
        <Route exact path="/" render={routeProps => <ArtistList {...routeProps}     artists={this.props.artists} />} />
        <Route exact path="/artist/:artistUrlName" component={Artist} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ArtistList.propTypes = {
  artists: PropTypes.array.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = function(state) {
  console.log('The state is:');
  console.log(state);
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        fetch: () => dispatch(ArtistsListActions.fetchArtists())
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App); //Pass new method here
```